# Check only one checkbox and unchek others

Tags: jquery, onsen-ui

Im trying to check only one checkbox at the time and others uncheck , but when i want to check new chekcbox then pervious will uncheck and so on.

i tried this code:

JS file

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
$(".check_class").attr("checked", false);
$(this).attr("checked", true);    
});
```

HTML file

```
    <ons-list-header>Takistused</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
      <label class="checkbox checkbox--noborder checkbox--list-item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="example">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--noborder__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark"></div>
        vihmaveerenn
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable">
      <label class="checkbox checkbox--noborder checkbox--list-item" id="test">
        <input type="checkbox" id="example">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--noborder__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark" ></div>
        äärekivi
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" >
      <label class="checkbox checkbox--noborder checkbox--list-item" id="test1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="example">
        <div class="checkbox__checkmark checkbox--noborder__checkmark checkbox--list-item__checkmark"></div>
        munakivi tee
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
```

What im doing wrong? i have tried different approaches, but it just wont work in live use.

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons? That's what they are for :) (you can always style them to look like checkboxes if you insist)

Comment: Please note your example is invalid HTML as you have duplicate IDs

Comment: TrueBlueAussie TNX for your advice.

Comment: You need to use radio buttons, this is what they are made for.

Comment: TrueBlueAussie , i appreciate your help, and your questin was the best couse u mentioned that i must be use radio buttons instead of checkboxes :)

Comment: Glad you liked it, so why did you select the other, later, answer?

Comment: couse you are smart and know everithing but we need to aprove these guys do , who are just beginners in here, and they try to help. ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the `.not(this)` like bellow:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {      
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="one" />
<input type="checkbox" id="two" />
<input type="checkbox" id="three" />
<input type="checkbox" id="four" />
```

Comment: TNX :) for help, i have forgotten html id rules :)

Comment: It would be better if you used radios as @TrueBlueAussie says

Comment: Also note: the `if` check here is not needed as it cannot be in a state where that could matter.

Answer (score 5):

You should really use radio buttons for this type of functionality, however you can simply exclude an item from a set of matches with `not` like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4n2e31oq/

Note you need to use `prop` and not `attr` for certain properties like `checked`.

You can make this a little more efficient by caching the selection of checkboxes:

```
var $checks = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
$checks.click(function() {
   $checks.not(this).prop("checked", false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4n2e31oq/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
             var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%= chkBranchRoleTransaction.ClientID %>');
            var chks = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
             for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                 chks[i].checked = false;
             }
             $(this)[0].checked = true;
         });
    });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this using class. You have add class and remove except current element.

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.esg-filterbutton', function() { 
    jQuery(this).addClass('selected');     
    jQuery('.esg-filterbutton').not(this).removeClass('selected');  
});
```